# Cannot create user control via "Create as a UserControl..." menu in the "Blend for Visual Studio 2022"

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

1. I created new solution and project in the "Blend for Visual Studio 2022".
2. There is a "MainWindow.xaml" file and I can place some controls such as Button, Checkbox, etc.
3. I select all controls and click the mouse right button. And then menu is popped-up.
4. I click the menu "Create as a UserControl...".
5. I typed name of user control like a "MyUserControl" and click "OK" button.
6. Nothing happened.

I expected the user control is created by automatically. But the user control is not created.
Is it a bug in the Blend for Visual Studio 2022 version?
As I remember, it works properly in the older version of "Microsoft Expression Blend".